# (Laravel 8) How to check if user permissions are something (No-package, No Spatie)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I got User, Roles ,Permissions and role_user, role_permission.

What I want to do is:

- check in User modal what the request user his permissions are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel suggest `gate policy` for authorization. The best method is learn it:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

But if you want to work with your own method.you can use a middleware and add it to all routes you want to protect them.

```
php artisan make:middleware MyauthMiddleware
```

Put this code in it:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
class MyauthMiddleware
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next,$permission_id)
{
    if (Auth::user()) { // if user is logined
        // Do what you want from your tables. 
        // Here is the most important part you should use.
        //I wrote sample bellow:
        $roles = RoleUser::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
        foreach($roles as $role_user){
            if($role_user->role->permision->id == $permission_id){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }
    }
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Then add the new middleware class in the $`middleware` property of your `app/Http/Kernel.php` class.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //....
    'myauthcheck' => \App\Http\Middleware\MyauthMiddleware::class,
];
```

Then set the middelware on your route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'myauthcheck:832'], function () {     
//your routes here related to 832 permission_id
});
```

Comment: Ok, i understand. But even if i do this. What do i have to write to check if user has (...) permission? I know how to check user role but permission has no pivot table to user so its kinda confusing.

Comment: @ChrisServ I edited my answer and add some details. Check it again.

Comment: For using this line `$role->permission->id` you should have relation `hasMany` to `permission` in `Role` Model.

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `roles` where `user_id` = 1)

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Use RoleUser model rather than Role class in my answer

Comment: I cant use UserRole like that. Someone told me a pivot table isnt supposed to have a modal and controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you are looking for a way to query on your database. Unfortunately you can't do this with Laravel's Eloquent ORM directly and needs some additional effort which is not very efficient in my opinion. So this is the way with SQL:

```
SELECT `permissions`.* FROM `permissions` JOIN `role_permission` ON (`permissions`.`id` = `role_permission`.`permission_id`) WHERE `role_permission`.`role_id` IN (SELECT `role_id` FROM `user_role` WHERE `user_role`.`user_id` = $USER_ID)
```

I hope it'd help you.